# How to integrate Rest API and MongoDB Based Spring Boot Application to Drools and KIE Server?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, drools, drools-planner

I am looking for any solution for REST API based Spring Boot Application has to be integrated or import to KIE server to apply Drools Rules and Business Flow.

There are close questions but there is not related with a newer version of Spring Boot versions because Spring.io does not support JBooss/Drools and KIE server.

Please give me feedback on how or simple project configuration.